# Displaying multiple legends in a single trace in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, networkx, plotly-dash

So the [docs](https://plotly.com/python/legend/) pretty much make it look like displaying multiple legends for different items of the same `trace` (`plotly.graph_objs.Scatter`) isn't something that `Plotly` supports by default. You should rather keep adding new traces to Figure and each of these traces contains its own legend.

However, this seems cumbersome for my specific case. What I have is a graph in `Plotly Dash` where the user can search for different nodes & paths and so I am defining different colors according to the search and all of this within a single trace (by making use of [colorscale](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#scatter-marker-line-colorscale) & color from Scatter).

When a user searches for different nodes in the graph I am coloring them uniquely. I'd like to specifically show a legend for each of the different colors which highlight these nodes.

Is it possible to do this in a single trace?

Comment: According to this [source](https://community.plotly.com/t/add-custom-legend-markers-color-to-plotly-python/19635/2) each legend item requires a corresponding trace. So the only way to make this work is splitting up your trace into many traces. Plotly is very poor in this regard compared to matplotlib where you can just set whatever legend you like. In trying to automate things for you Plotly took some freedom in turn. Can I ask you why you need to use Plotly? Networkx already comes with matplotlib plotting support.

Comment: Just because it goes nicely with [Dash](https://dash.plotly.com/). So when I started this I went for Dash, Plotly & NetworkX. Yeah I read that too but I suppose I was hopping sth had changed. Though there seems to be an open [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1668) since years now...

Comment: There is also an [option](https://community.plotly.com/t/is-it-possible-to-use-custom-plotly-offline-iplot-mpl-code-in-dash/6897) to plot matplotlib figures in Dash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently this is not possible. There is no such example in the [docs](https://plotly.com/python/legend/) though there is an [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1668) on this topic since a couple of years now.