# Plotly scatter (bubble plot) marker size in legend

Tags: python, plotly

Is there a way to show marker size (bubble size) within the legend of a graph in plotly express (plotly python). For example using the code below, it shows the population using the marker size.

```
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year==2007")
fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", color="continent",
    size="pop", size_max=45, log_x=True)
fig.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Matplotlib has something similar using the `.legend_elements("sizes")` (see here, [creating a matplotlib scatter legend size related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164797/creating-a-matplotlib-scatter-legend-size-related)), was wondering if there is something in Plotly as well.

Comment: This is not available at the moment, you can follow this issue to receive updated https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/5099

Comment: These posts are asking the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66686072/size-legend-for-plotly-express-scatterplot-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71694358/bubble-size-legend-with-python-plotly

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple scatter plots, the size of the legend is basically linked to the size of each marker. As a means of aligning them, you can use the raft setting.[API here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-legend-itemsizing) [Offical Reference](https://plotly.com/python/legend/#size-of-legend-items)

```
fig.update_layout(legend= {'itemsizing': 'trace'})
# Constant: same, Trace: individual marker size
```

The marker size of your question is a categorical variable, so there is no effect of changing the size.

Comment: In the above plot, i would like to have a sub legend (apart from the categorial legend) which shows the size of the marker in relationship to a variable. The `itemsizing` attribute is operating globally, is there a way to control it for grouped legends.

Comment: Something similar to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582584/how-to-simultaneously-apply-color-shape-size-in-a-scatter-plot-using-plotly

Comment: plotly does not seem to support multiple legends at this time. I am referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62780182/displaying-multiple-legends-in-a-single-trace-in-plotly) and from the [development community](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/5099).